# How do I create a class with the specified characteristics?

Tags: python, class

What I want to do is to create a class that I will call a `Cluster` that I can use to store representations of multivariable data points. Like a bunch of people's heights, weights, and ages. I want to make it so when I create an instance of `Cluster`, it returns an empty dictionary. I then want to be able to add key value pairs. I want each value paired with each key to *only* be a list. I want each list to only contain only 1 data type.

However, they don't have to be the same data type for every list. What I mean is that one list can only consists of integers, and the other list is only full of strings. I even allow a list of tuples or lists or dictionaries. They don't even have to have the same data type for each value in itself. But, the overall list must then contain all dictionaries, tuples, etc.

Example of a `Cluster`:

```
{'Hobbies': [(3, 's', {'name': 'Sam'}), (4, 5), (), (True)], 'Weights': [1, 34, 3, 90]}
```

Notice how the above 'Hobbies' value pair is a list of *only* tuples and the 'Weights' value pair is a list of *only* integers. This is what I mean by what I am trying to say above.

I created a function that generates what a `Cluster` full of values should *look* like, but I want it to be a class. It gives you what I want to happen, but I want make a `class`, not a function that generates it. Other methods such as getting the length of the `Cluster` I can figure out, I just want everything that I said above to be true.

```
from random import randint


def create_cluster(a, b, c, *d):
    cluster = {}
    for key in d:
        point = []
        for integer in range(0, a):
            point.append(randint(b, c))
        cluster[key] = point
    return cluster


print(create_cluster(4, 2, 9, 'Height', 'Weight', 'Age'))
```

Output:

```
{'Height': [5, 3, 3, 6], 'Weight': [7, 3, 5, 7], 'Age': [9, 5, 3, 6]}
```

Comment: So are you asking how to enforce that the lists are homogeneous? That is that the elements of a given list all have the same type? Python doesn't have any mechanism to do that.

Comment: Also, where is the class? All I see is you are returning a dictionary.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Could I make it so it checks each value in the list until it comes up with a mismatch and then reports an error?

Comment: I have not used it much, but i think attrs validators could be used to do what you want... https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/ ... you wouldn't have to check all the entries, if the current list is empty, allow anything, otherwise check against entry 0 is sufficient.

Comment: Is this purely for learning purposes?

Comment: @AMC yes and no. I mean the answers that I have gotten have helped me learn a LOT more useful stuff about python, but has also answered my question.

Comment: @PythonHunter Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I meant to ask whether you were trying to create your own solution _to store representations of multivariable data points_ as a way of learning, or if you actually intend to use it for something "serious".

Comment: @AMC OH, it is meant for learning

Answer (score 0):

As Code-Apprentice mentions, there is no mechanism by which python **enforces** type checking in the sense that it will stop you from compiling and running the code. As of version 3.5, however, Python allows you to implement a soft type checking - you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b). What this means is that Python now offers you a way too check to see if your code is passing illegal values to functions/classes/variables etc.

Here's how it works:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Any, Tuple, Union
from random import randint

class Cluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data: Dict[str, List[Any]] = {}

    def create_cluster(self, a, b, c, *d):
        for key in d:
            point = []
            for integer in range(0, a):
                point.append(randint(b, c))
            self.data[key] = point

clust = Cluster()
clust.create_cluster(4, 2, 9, 'Height', 'Weight', 'Age')
print(clust.data)
```

Edit: for your example specifically, you'd want something like:

```
self.data: Dict[str, List[Union[Tuple, int]] = {}
```

Union is a type that indicates a wildcard of specified possibilities, so the dictionary value can be a list containing either tuples or ints. I guess if you wanted to further restrict the data types inside the tuples, you could do:

```
self.data: Dict[str, List[Union[Tuple[Union[int, str]], int]] = {}
```

Next, [you need mypy installed](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html). Mypy has to be called separately from a terminal on your script, but it will go through the code and perform a type check - that is, it will alert you to any instances where you have declared illegal variables in your class.

Alternatively, you could perform a series of in-code catches involving:

```
if type(data['Weight'][0]) != whatever:
    raise("You're putting the wrong type of variable in")
```

But mypy seems like a better solution in the longer term. It'll save you from having to wait for your code to execute, run, and fail in a predictable spot.

Feedback and corrections welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you need, we can actually make a dict object that will type check for you! 
No imports needed.

We just have to subclass the dict class, and override the functions for adding items to the dictionary, so we can type check before allowing any additions.

Here is the code below.

```
class ClusterDict(dict):
    key_type = str  # we want all of our keys to be str type
    value_type = list  # same for our value as a list

    # lets override the function for dictionary assignment so we can type check before we add to our dictionary
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.type_check_and_add(key, value)

    # Lets override update as well
    def update(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.type_check_and_add(key, value)

    def type_check_and_add(self, key: str, value: list) -> None:
        assert type(key) == self.key_type, f"Expected {self.key_type} for key, got {type(key)} instead."
        if type(value) is not list:
            value = [value]  # Make it a list if its isn't, remove this if you know it will always come as a list, even if its a single entry, like [5], or [(2, 6)]
        assert type(value) == self.value_type, f"Expected {self.value_type} for key, got {type(value)} instead."
        val_type = type(value[0])  # type of first item in list, lets make sure they all match this one
        for val in value:
            assert type(val) == val_type, f"Items do not have matching types for key {key}."
        super().__setitem__(key, value)  # this then passes assignment as usual to the base class dict
```

Lets do some tests now!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    clust = ClusterDict()
    input_data = {
        'Height': [4, 3, 5],
        'Age': [(4, 9), (4, 6, 8)]
    }
    clust.update(**input_data)
    print(clust)
```

```
{'Height': [4, 3, 5], 'Age': [(4, 9), (4, 6, 8)]}
```

Looks good so far, we can add whole dictionaries using update as usual

```
    input_data = {'Weights': [1, 34, 3, 90]}
    clust.update(**input_data)
    print(clust)
```

```
{'Height': [4, 3, 5], 'Age': [(4, 9), (4, 6, 8)], 'Weights': [1, 34, 3, 90]}
```

Or just one entry at a time.

Lets try the usual way, dict[key] = value

```
    clust['Hobbies'] = [(3, 's', {'name': 'Sam'}), (4, 5), (), (True,)]
    print(clust)
```

```
{'Height': [4, 3, 5], 'Age': [(4, 9), (4, 6, 8)], 'Weights': [1, 34, 3, 90], 'Hobbies': [(3, 's', {'name': 'Sam'}), (4, 5), (), (True,)]}
```

Looking good. But now lets try adding a list with types that don't match.

```
    clust['My Favorite Number'] = [7, '7', (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
    print(clust)
```

```
    assert type(val) == val_type, f"Items do not have matching types for key {key}."
AssertionError: Items do not have matching types for key My Favorite Number.
```

Which throws an AssertionError and prevents us from doing so, like we wanted.

Bonus though, because we subclassed dict, we get all of its methods for free!

```
>>>len(clust)
4

for k, v in clust.items():
...     print(k, v)
...     
Height [4, 3, 5]
Age [(4, 9), (4, 6, 8)]
Weights [1, 34, 3, 90]
Hobbies [(3, 's', {'name': 'Sam'}), (4, 5), (), (True,)]
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for and it helps!

Comment: if you need to have this work during runtime, whenever you want to add to a cluster, wrap it in a :try: except AssertionError:" and deal with it as the program requires, since you had incorrect data.